# Не считывается соприкосновение двух коллайдеров в Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два 2d объекта : один из них начинает двигаться при нажатии клавиши , а другой просто стоит на одном месте.
При соприкосновении двух объектов первый останавливается и переносится в точку x,но проблема бывает в том что иногда действие не происходит.
 P.S Есть предположение ,что один объект просто проходит сквозь другой из-за большой скорости и соприкосновение не успевает считываться .
-Обычно первый объект перед тем как остановится и перенестись в точку x проходит где-то наполовину сквозь другой , поэтому и сделал такое предположение.
Первый объект двигаю кодом :

```
    public float moveSpeedPlayer;
    float speedX;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
                    speedX += moveSpeedPlayer;
                    Player.transform.Translate(0, speedX, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Приведите код движения объекта и другую информацию, чтобы можно быть понять, в чем ваша проблема. Сейчас есть подозрение, что вы двигаете объект с помощью изменения transform.position (или translate) и ждете, что физика будет вести себя адекватно

Comment: Да, я использую transform.Translate